# Problem with DatePicker example on Android. Possible Android bug

Tags: android, timepicker

I am implementing a DateTimePicker. I have reuse this [repository](http://code.google.com/p/datetimepicker/).

The problem appears when I am trying to catch the events for the `onTimeChanged()` method when I change the minutes. If I use the buttons of **+** and **–** it's fine, the event is fired and I can handle it here:

```
public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    // Update the internal Calendar instance
    mCalendar.set(mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                  mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                  mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
                  hourOfDay, minute);
}
```

Whereas when I click on the minutes and I change it using the keyboard the event doesn't arise, as in the case of the hours, days, etc…

A more detail description of the problem is:

*What steps will reproduce the problem?*

1. Select the time picker
2. Touch on the numbers, so the keyboard appears
3. when I write an amout of minutes, the event doesn't fire

*What is the expected output? What do you see instead?*

I would expect to catch this event inside `onTimeChanged()`, but I cant.

*What version of the product are you using? On what operating system?*

Version 2. On Android Froyo.

The author of this code has told me there is a bug on Android. I think should be a work around to this problem, for example creating my own class extending from TimePicker and reimplementing the interface OnTimeChangedListener.

What is the best option to listen the timerPicker events?

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: What is the best option to listen the timerPicker events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DatePicker control must call clearFocus() in order to trigger
onFocusChanged() and that will fix the issue.

PFB the link that might help you :

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2745

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The event is fired in the same way as the `onchange` Event in HTML:

It only fires after leaving the text boxes, and going to the next one.

I can't tell if it's really a bug or some kind of feature.

---

You could just catch the [`KeyEvent.Callback`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.Callback.html) when extending the `TimePicker` class. Then you should get informed about every single key press inside the `EditText` controls internally used by the `TimePicker`.